# WordPress Site wp-admin URL issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a website: **www.webklh.com**

and I created a addon domain:**free-jlpt.com**

using hostgator's addon function

the matching path is **/public_html/free-jlpt.com/**

free-jlpt.com works fine

but **www.webklh.com/wp-admin** has problem

it redirecs to the URL below so I can't login

http://webklh.com/jlpt/wp-login.php/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webklh.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Here is my site's file structure

any suggesstion?

[image: file structure]

Answer (score 1):

Hi generally it is plugin and theme conflict issue so you want to **disabled plugins and theme** for temporary and then needs to check also check your database wp-options table which url in it please check

Please find below links for more help

1) http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-login-page-refreshing-and-redirecting-issue/

2) https://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-login-keeps-redirecting

3) https://wordpress.org/support/topic/login-problems-redirects-me